# Different parameters in TFS test with shared steps

Tags: testing, tfs

Title: Different parameters in TFS test with shared steps.

I have a situation where I write a (manual) testcases in TFS (Server Version 15.117.27024.0)

I created a shared step with 2 parameter values. 
How do I call the same shared step, with different parameter values, from within the same testcase?

in pseudo-code:

```
test_case (
    shared_steps('param1','param2');
    shared_steps('param3','param4');
    step3();
    step4();
)
```

From the web interface, and various (old) blogpost, it seems like this is not possible, if that is indeed the case, I would like to have that verified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible.

We can only open the shared steps (double click the shared step) to see the parameter values within the same test case.